# Draggable dialog

Tags: android

I need to make a dialog draggable, and I found no way to do it, so I toyed with PopupWindow, and got it to be draggable.

Is anybody aware of a standard android way to achieve a draggable dialog, or a better way than mine (implementing dialog-behaviour inside PopupWindow), or should I go on with the popupwindow?

Best regards!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, `PopupWindow` is pretty much the simplest way in the framework to achieve this behavior.

Comment: I'll go with the 11.7k, I suppose. Thanks again!